# Batching with Google Places: Is it possible?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-api-client

I was wondering if it's possible to send batched requests to `maps.googleapis.com`.  As far as I can tell, it isn't.

I was using the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/batch) with supports batching, but it's only for `www.googleapis.com`.  I went ahead and hacked it so that I could call the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation), and it worked fine for normal calls, but when I actually tried to batch them, I got a 404 error:

"The requested URL `/batch` was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

So it appears that `maps.googleapis.com` does not support batching, but I wanted to be sure this is true. If anyone knows otherwise, please tell me how.  Thanks!

inside **google-api-php-client/src/Google/Config.php**:

```
-      'base_path' => 'https://www.googleapis.com',
+      'base_path' => 'https://maps.googleapis.com',
```

**google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Maps.php**:

(I added this file to make Places calls possible.)

```
<?php

class Google_Service_Maps extends Google_Service
{
  const MAPS = "https://maps.googleapis.com/auth/maps";
  public function __construct(Google_Client $client)
  {
    parent::__construct($client);
    $this->servicePath = 'maps/api/';
    $this->version = 'v3';
    $this->serviceName = 'maps';

    $this->places = new Google_Service_Maps_Places_Resource(
        $this,
        $this->serviceName,
        'places',
        array(
          'methods' => array(
            'autocomplete' => array(
              'path' => 'place/autocomplete/json',
              'httpMethod' => 'GET',
              'parameters' => array(
                'input' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ),
                'sensor' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'boolean',
                  'required' => true,
                ),
                'location' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                ),
                'radius' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'integer',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        )
    );
  }
}

class Google_Service_Maps_Places_Resource extends Google_Service_Resource
{

  public function autocomplete($input, $lat, $lng, $radius, $optParams = array())
  {
    $params = array('input' => $input, 'location' => "$lat,$lng", 'radius' => $radius, 'sensor' => false);
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('autocomplete', array($params));
  }
}
```

**API batch calling code**:

```
<?php

const API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';

set_include_path("google-api-php-client/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Maps.php';
require_once 'Google/Http/Batch.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey(API_KEY);

$client->setUseBatch(true);
$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);

$service = new Google_Service_Maps($client);

$inputs = array(
    'Dolore',
    'MacAl',
    'App Aca'
);

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    $req = $service->places->autocomplete($input, 37.7833, -122.4167, 500);
    $batch->add($req, $input);
}

$results = $batch->execute();

print_r($results);

print_r($req);
```

Comment: What error did you get using Places API?

Comment: An example request maybe? Could you be running into some of the API limitations in terms of number of requests per sec or day?

Comment: it's not a request limitation.  The error was **404 Not Found**.  I didn't get this error except when I called `/batch` to make a batched request.